# Create all discontinuous subsequences of fixed length from sequence

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a sequence like the following:

```
seq = "SDLKFJSOIDHFSODIF"
```

I want to make all discontinuous subsequences of length 5 for this. Because there are 5 possible reading frames, I want a list of 5 lists like the following:

```
[["SDLKF", "JSOID", "HFSOD"], ["DLKFJ", "SOIDH", FSODI"], ...]
```

All of the characters will not be present in each list, and for this example, the 5th list will only have two entries. This is okay.

How can I make a function that generalizes this to all possible lengths of the subsequence?

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [[seq[i: i + 5] for i in range(j, len(seq), 5) if i + 5 <= len(seq)] for j in range(5)]
[['SDLKF', 'JSOID', 'HFSOD'],
 ['DLKFJ', 'SOIDH', 'FSODI'],
 ['LKFJS', 'OIDHF', 'SODIF'],
 ['KFJSO', 'IDHFS'],
 ['FJSOI', 'DHFSO']]
```

Comment: Nice. I think you could replace the `if` clause with `range(j, len(seq)-5+1, 5)` also.

Answer (score 0):

Although the single list comprehension is the better answer, here is a [`more-itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools)<sup>1</sup> approach.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


seq = "SDLKFJSOIDHFSODIF"
size = 5
```

**Code**

```
windows = it.islice(mit.stagger(seq, offsets=range(len(seq)), longest=True), size)
[["".join(x) for x in mit.sliced(w, size) if None not in x and len(x) == size] for w in windows]
```

Output

```
[['SDLKF', 'JSOID', 'HFSOD'],
 ['DLKFJ', 'SOIDH', 'FSODI'],
 ['LKFJS', 'OIDHF', 'SODIF'],
 ['KFJSO', 'IDHFS'],
 ['FJSOI', 'DHFSO']]
```

---

**Details**

Goal: make several **sliding windows** of the sequence and split them into **chunks**.

In the first list comprehension, the results are *shrinking* **sliding `windows`**. For demonstration, here is an example of the full cascading results:

```
>>> windows = mit.stagger(seq, offsets=range(len(seq)), longest=True)
>>> ["".join(filter(None, w)) for w in windows]
['SDLKFJSOIDHFSODIF',
'DLKFJSOIDHFSODIF',
'LKFJSOIDHFSODIF',
'KFJSOIDHFSODIF',
'FJSOIDHFSODIF',
'JSOIDHFSODIF',
'SOIDHFSODIF',
'OIDHFSODIF',
'IDHFSODIF',
'DHFSODIF',
'HFSODIF',
'FSODIF',
'SODIF',
'ODIF',
'DIF',
'IF',
'F']
```

Notice for each window, the left side *slides*, while the right side is fixed.  In other words, the window size shrinks by 1 for each iteration.  These shrinking windowing are achieved by the `offsets` parameter in `more_itertools.stagger` (see [the docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.stagger) for details).  Since the process repeats, only the first windows of a given `size` are selected via [`itertools.isliced`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

The second comprehension simply **chunks** these windows into groups of a `size`, discarding invalid chunks (`< size` or containing the fillvalue `None`, a default in `more_itertools.stagger`).

<sub><sup>1</sup>`more_itertools` is a third-party library installed via [`pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).</sub>